# BlackBerry Dialog box

Tags: java, blackberry

I have some Android code, where I'm using `Dialog` class to display

```
public void createCustomDialog(String msg)
{
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
   dialog.setTitle("Error");
   dialog.setCancelable(true);
   TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
   text.setText(msg);
   ImageView img = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
   img.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
   dialog.show();
 }
```

Can anyone help me with the corresponding Blackberry code for it

Comment: are you asking about android or blackberry?

Comment: for any one in future, here's a good tutorial on how to work with [Blackberry Dialogs in java](http://www.thepcwizard.in/2013/01/bb-java-dialog.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the BlackBerry [Dialog](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html) class to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You would use this:

```
Dialog.alert(String message);
```

as follows:

```
Dialog.alert.("This is a Dialog!");
```

Output (In a Dialog Box):

```
This is a Dialog!
```

To add Image Please see :
http://www.javaquery.com/2011/07/how-to-put-image-in-dialog-box.html